# How do I resolve the versioning difference between iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

When making a hotfix on Flutter, we can easily upload to the google play store + build with flutter with version `x.x.x+x`, in my case `3.3.12+1`. However, when uploading to the Apple's app store, I get this error

```
[!] Error uploading ipa file: 
 [Application Loader Error Output]: ERROR: Asset validation failed (90186) Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '3.3.12' is closed for new build submissions (ID: 1d36e0c0-be56-4ab6-8cb3-4650f203c557)
[Application Loader Error Output]: ERROR: Asset validation failed (90062) This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [3.3.12] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [3.3.12]. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring (ID: ca097509-b99e-48c7-9010-cefeba930c73)
[Application Loader Error Output]: Error uploading '/var/folders/bl/wbxjgtzx7j5_mjsmfr3ynlc00000gp/T/438bf7fc-df62-4cbd-b9d2-dd9eb4465192.ipa'.
[Application Loader Error Output]: Asset validation failed Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '3.3.12' is closed for new build submissions (ID: 1d36e0c0-be56-4ab6-8cb3-4650f203c557) (90186)
[Application Loader Error Output]: Asset validation failed This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [3.3.12] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [3.3.12]. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring (ID: ca097509-b99e-48c7-9010-cefeba930c73) (90062)
[Application Loader Error Output]: The call to the altool completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
```

Is there an alternative to the `+1` versioning for iOS? or do I *have* to increment it up to `3.3.13`?

Comment: Versions on ios need to be integers separated by .  No one except you cares about version numbers. Just use x.x.x on both platforms

Answer (score 0):

for apple you should increase version from
`3.3.12+1` to `3.3.13+1`

You could do the same for android just for coherence.

in this case in app store version code(+2) will be updated automaticaly. more info [Build and release an iOS app](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios)